# Using For loop to call a function

Tags: php, function, for-loop

I need some help with this function to finish my project.

3 variables:

```
$cityName1 = "New York";
$cityName2 = "Madrid";
$cityName3 = "Paris";
```

The function:

```
function cityNameFunction($cityName) {
    $city_name = $cityName;
    return $city_name;
}
```

Calling the function:

```
$cityName = array();
for($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $cityName[$x] = ${'cityName'.$x};
}
$cityName1 = cityNameFunction($cityName1);
$cityName2 = cityNameFunction($cityName2);
$cityName3 = cityNameFunction($cityName3);
```

What do I have to do if I have 2000 cities?

Thanks for any help

Comment: What should be the use of this code?

Comment: This is just a example for my real code, otherwise you won't understand my language. I just want to return the name of every city.

Comment: Where do you have 2000 cities. What I mean is, in what data structure do you have these city names?

Comment: The question makes no sense without more background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strange example, but you may write something like this

```
$cityName = array();
for ($x = 1; $x <= 3; $x++) {
    $cityName[$x] = ${'cityName'.$x};
    ${'cityName'.$x} = cityNameFunction(${'cityName'.$x});
}
```

Comment: Thank you mnv. I will try it.

Comment: Your code works perfect of my example. Now I will try it on my real code. You will hear it from me:)

Answer (score 0):

An example of Itterating over a PHP Function at work:

```
$new = array(1,2,3,4);
    for($i=0;$i<=3;$i++)
    {
        $val = $new[$i];
        if(!function_exists('myfunction'))
        {
            function myfunction($value) {
                //Do something
            }
        }
        echo $val;
    }
```